# How can we expand the lightning component to full screen

Tags: salesforce, lwc, lightning, aura-framework

I have the requirement to expand the lightning component on whole screen.
I tried the css but that's not worked. But None of them working
.maincontent{
height: 100%;
background-color: deepskyblue;
}

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: deepskyblue; }



Please suggest the way to achieve it.

Current Page:-

[![Current][1]][1]


Expectation :-
[![Expectation][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuI6K.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZhs.png
```